# Understanding behavior of clousers and event listeners in React component with WebSocket call

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, websocket

I have the following component:

```
function SocketClient() {
 const [socket, setSocket]= React.useState(null);
  const [msg, setMsg] = React.useState([]);

  function handleMessage(event) {
    setMsg([...msg, String(event.data)]);
  }

  if(!socket){
    const newSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/ws");
    newSocket.addEventListener("open", function(){
    newSocket.send("Hello Server!");
  });
    newSocket.addEventListener("message", handleMessage);
    setSocket(newSocket);
  }

  function click() {
    if (socket) {
      socket?.send("hooooooonk");
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Shared Component</p>
      <button onClick={click}>HONK</button>
      <pre><code>
        {JSON.stringify(msg, null, "    ")}
        </code></pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have been trying different ways of creating a websocket connection inside a react component. This is one of a few methods I have tried, in which I store the socket in local state, and then only create a socket if there currently isn't one (`if(!socket) {...`), to avoid creating a new connection every time the component refreshes.

However, when I add the event listeners inside of the conditional statement, I ran into the following issue: the `msg` variable (also a local state variable) gets stuck in its initial value.

- So, when the component loads, `msg` is an empty Array.
- Once the websocket connection is created and the "open" handler runs, the value of `msg` is set to `["Hello Server!"]`, and this reflects on the component's body.
- However, after I send a new message, I would expect `msg` to have a value of `["Hello Server!", "hooooooonk"]`, but the last value just keeps replacing the existing one.
- I verified that everytime `handleMessage` runs it is reading the value of `msg` as an empty array (or whatever value I initialized it to).

So my question is, why does this happen? My understanding of closures is that `handleMessage` should keep reading the updated value of `msg`. Am I wrong in that understanding or is this something introduced by the hooks API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always safest to use the functional form of the useState setter:

```
setMsg(msg => [...msg, String(event.data)]);
```

This will always get the current value of the variable as the argument and avoids a lot of common pitfall.

I believe in your case the pitfall is that you redefine the `handleMessage` function every time the component renders, and what `msg` refers to at that point is unclear -- seems like at the time of rendering react still uses the default value of `msg`. There are other ways to avoid this pitfall (I think `useCallback` might work here, too), but the above is probably the best and most compact solution.

I would also put your `if(!socket){` block into a useEffect instead.

Comment: `functional form of the useEffect setter` probably you meant [functional form of useState setter](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)?

Comment: Thanks! That seems to solve it. `useEffect` was another one of my issues, but I ran into the same.

So this is a specific hooks issue then?

Comment: @PabloBarríaUrenda it is not a specific hook issue, it is just a closure. Every rerender is basically the functional component code reexecution, with own local variables. On first render `msg` was pointing to some array in memory, you used `setMsg` which does not modify `msg` itself in current render, current scope, it creates a new array (as per your code) with new reference and this reference is assigned to `msg` on next render from `useState` hook. But old array still exists, and this old array is closure captured in the specific component render when listeners were set.

Comment: @SergeySosunov thanks. I guess it is "a specific hook issue" only in the sense that it is brought on by something the hook does which I am taking for granted and not fully understanding, but I do get your point. Time to look under the hood at how these magical things work.